# Split a text without whitespaces by words in list

Tags: java, string, list, split, java-stream

I have three lists, that I have merged into one list

```
    static List allLists = Stream.of(list1, list2, list3)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have user input without whitespaces

```
String = "HelloIwanttobookanonlineseminaratyourcompany"
```

All the words in the user input `String` are already in `allLists`. I want to iterare over `allLists` and insert whitespaces into the String, with every word found. The result should be:

```
String = "Hello I want to book an online seminar at your company"
```

Is there an easy solution I miss?

Comment: There is no easy solution, because maybe I want to book anon line seminar. In other words: there are multiple ways to tokenize the same string with the same word lists.

Comment: But if "an" and "online" are in my list, but "anon" is not, it should only scan for the words in my list.

Comment: Again, there can be the word "He" _and_ the word "Hello". What would be the desired output for your example?

Comment: In this case there will only be the word "hello" in allLists, not the word "he"

Comment: O.K. maybe I wasn't quite clear. My question to you is: What if you have "he", "hello" **and** "llo" in your `allList`? (If we can suppose that "llo" is the acceptable word).

Comment: I see. I have not thought about this, since I have three lists with a limited number of words (around 10 each) that do not share many similarities. In your case, it will be way more complicated, I suppose.

Comment: The real question here is why on Earth do you "have user input without whitespaces"? It looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) where you are focusing on fixing symptoms instead of cause of the problem.

Comment: @Pshemo: some speech-to-text problem I need to fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a one-liner that employs a (massive) look behind built from `allLists` to insert spaces before each word:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=" + String.join("|", allLists) + ")", " ");
```

Note that order of words in `allLists` is important; if you want longer words to take preference, list them first (recommended). Eg if both "book" and "booking" are in your list, put booking before book, otherwise you’ll get "book ing" in your result.

Comment: Please, help me to understand your answer (b/c I hate regex).
What should be the order of words in `allList` if I have book, booking, boo, king?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this

Comment: List words in the order of preference of spacing - the first hit will get a space after it. This solution is “simple”, but may not work for you because it won’t backtrack if it can’t find a path though the string such that the result is only spaced known words.

Comment: @colin I changed it slightly to use a look behind rather than a look ahead

Comment: It doesn’t matter, in which order `"book"` and `"booking"` appear in the list. The look-behind will always detect `"book"` *and* `"booking"` when looking behind, as they appear at different text positions. Obviously, you can construct similar problematic examples when using look-ahead, not to speak of words that can be found in the middle of another words, in both cases. The error starts with the decision to use a zero-width pattern, instead of just consuming the word. When you use `str.replaceAll(String.join("|", allLists), "$0 ")` and order the words in the list, you don’t have the problem.